# Material UI, custom Slider markings , nth-child selector

Tags: material-ui, slider

[image]

As a newbie to Material UI, was  playing around customization of Slider component, tried to implement custom marking with an odd index on one side and even-index based on the opposite side,
noticed that nth-child(odd) or nth-child(even) not working ,, with some tweaks and trials finally found that
the following are working

**nth-child(n)
nth-child(4n+1)**

Here comes my Question
why odd , even and 2n+1 are not working ,

[image]

```
const marks = [];

for (let v = 0; v < 11; v++) {
  marks.push({ value: v * 10, label: (v * 10).toString() });
}

const MSlider8 = () => {
  // const sh = 10
  // const mh = 30
  // const mt = 13 + sh + mh/2 + 2
  // const mlt = mh+20+sh

  // for upside
  //  mt = -(13+sh-mh/2 -4)
  return (
    <Slider
      marks={marks}
      sx={{
        //   "& .MuiSlider-mark:nth-child(3n)": {
        //         backgroundColor: "red",
        //         height:40,
        //         width: 2,
        //         top: -9,
        //   },
        "& .MuiSlider-mark": {
          [`&:nth-child(n)`]: {
            backgroundColor: "green",
            height: 30,
            width: 2,
            top: 34,
          },
          [`&:nth-child(4n+1)`]: {
            backgroundColor: "red",
            height: 30,
            width: 2,
            top: -4,
          },
        },

        // "& .MuiSlider-markLabel": {
        //   top: 54,
        //   color: "purple",
        // },
        "& .MuiSlider-markLabel": {
            [`&:nth-child(n)`]: {
                 top:54,
                 color:'purple',
              },
              [`&:nth-child(4n+2)`]: {
                color:'red',
                top:-38
              },
           
        },
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puKQi.png):

Answer (score 0):

i was able to customize the mark completely using slots:

```
<Slider
  marks            
  slots={{ mark: CustomMark }}
  valueLabelDisplay="auto"
  ...
/>


type MarkProps = {
  "data-index": number
  className: string
  ownerState: {
    marks: boolean
    sx: {
      "& .MuiSlider-markLabel": {
        fontSize: string
      }
    }
    slots: {}
    size: string
    value: number
    max: number
    valueLabelDisplay: string
    isRtl: boolean
    min: number
    disabled: boolean
    disableSwap: boolean
    orientation: string
    color: string
    step: number
    track: string
    marked: boolean
    dragging: boolean
    focusedThumbIndex: number
  }
  markActive: boolean
  style: {
    right: string
  }
}

const CustomMark = (props:MarkProps) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={props.className}
      style={{
        ...props.style, // holds { right: <percentage> }
        position: "absolute",
        width: 5,
        height: 5,
        borderRadius: "50%",
        background: "red",
      }}
    ></div>
  );
};
```

to those who that is interested, here's the original implementation:

```
// import { SliderMark } from "@mui/material/Slider/Slider";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { slotShouldForwardProp } from "@mui/material/styles/styled";
export const SliderMark = styled("span", {
  name: "MuiSlider",
  slot: "Mark",
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) =>
    slotShouldForwardProp(prop) && prop !== "markActive",
  overridesResolver: (props, styles) => {
    const { markActive } = props;

    return [styles.mark, markActive && styles.markActive];
  },
})(({ theme, ownerState, markActive }) => ({
  position: "absolute",
  width: 2,
  height: 2,
  borderRadius: 1,
  backgroundColor: "currentColor",
  ...(ownerState.orientation === "horizontal" && {
    top: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-1px, -50%)",
  }),
  ...(ownerState.orientation === "vertical" && {
    left: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, 1px)",
  }),
  ...(markActive && {
    backgroundColor: (theme.vars || theme).palette.background.paper,
    opacity: 0.8,
  }),
}));
```

taken from [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/141dcfeaddd84ad308b44c107a7fe8e92a6e1fae/packages/mui-material/src/Slider/Slider.js#L311)